# Find "assignment" (=) operator in a string with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I know there are real REGEX gurus out there, and I kinda figured there's a patter that will do what I'm looking for.

(note: I'm using perl but can turn around formatting from many regex patterns if you have another favorite)

I'm looking for the assignment operator in strings (code). It doesn't have the be the world's most robust, but needs to be better than "go find the first =".

This is simple for a simple test

```
var a = "42";
```

With the above I can say something like

```
($before, $after) = m/([^=])\=(.*)/;
```

And I will get the values I need. But once it gets a little more complicated like:

```
myVar["this is my = key"] = "and this is my value";
```

Things get a little more complicated. As you can see there is an "=" in a string. I will need to ignore strings (preferably both single and double quoted).

Anyone have a nice little trick for this one? And yes, I have many other patterns that are challenging, but getting this one solved would be a great leap ahead.

I'm not opposed to doing something like replacing any "=" found in enclosing quotes, then running my search for my operator. Not sure.

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you actually doing? Lexing? Parsing? Which programming language is your input in? What differentiates an assignment operator from other occurences of the `=` character?

Comment: I'm actually doing a little light-weight code parsing. Think something like a syntax highlighter. I'm actually planning on aligning assignments in a selection of code (to be really specific)

Comment: While a regex might be a minor component of your final solution, regexes are not the primary tool used in this type of problem.  This is a lexing/parsing problem.  Look at http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lexing  (Lexing, by Curtis "Ovid" Poe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module [Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) (core module since perl 5) can handle the quoting for you. This example will take the first two "fields" separated by the delimiter `=`. As you can see, it is fairly literal and captures even whitespace, semi-colons and quotes. I assumed by your example that this was not a problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = quotewords('=', 1, $_);
    print Dumper { $key => $val }
}

__DATA__
var a = "42";
myVar["this is my = key"] = "and this is my value";
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'var a ' => ' "42";'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'myVar["this is my = key"] ' => ' "and this is my value";'
        };
```

Comment: Wow. awesome here. Thanks for the head-start. It's not as complete as the Lexing road I was just starting to walk down but at this moment I don't quite need that power.

Comment: @bladnman You're welcome. It should be noted that this solution might be fragile, depending on your input. What can be guaranteed is that it will handle quoted equal signs.